# calling class name in the header file

Tags: c++

I just stumbled a c++ code with a calling of a class name in the upper part of the header file for example

```
class CFoo;
class CBar
{
  ....
};
```

My question is, what is `class CFoo` for?

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is called a forward declaration.  It means that there IS a class named CFoo, that will be defined later in the file (or another include).  This is typically used for pointer members in classes, such as:

```
class CFoo;
class CBar {
    public:
        CFoo* object;
};
```

It is a hint to the C++ compiler telling it not to freak out that a type name is being used without being defined, even though it hasn't seen the full definition for CFoo yet.

Comment: why not just use a header file instead that contains the definition of CFoo, why use this method instead?

Comment: These can go in header files as well; suppose CFoo refers to the CBar class (circular referencing).  You sometimes would need a forward declaration in your header anyway, because you can't fully define one class without knowing that the other class exists.

Answer (score 1):

It's called a forward declaration.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration

Answer (score 1):

```
class CFoo;
```

Is just a declaration that the class exists; even if you haven't seen the definition yet, you can still play with (CFoo *) or (CFoo &) - that is, pointers and references to CFoo.

Comment: You can also define functions that return CFoo (by value).

Comment: Really?  That seems unlikely to me, because to return by value you'd need to know at least the size of CFoo.